# list.copy() in Python returns same reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, I have this code:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x.copy()
print(f'{x == y}')
```

Interestingly, the evaluation for `x == y` is `True`

But, as soon as start the mutation of `x` after `x.copy()`, `x == y` becomes `False`

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x.copy()
x[2] = 1000
print(f'{x == y}')
```

Does this mean, the new list is created after the mutation of the first list?

Comment: You create y, then modify x, so of course `x==y` is False...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.copy()` makes a copy of `x` which you then assign to `y`. `x` and `y` are now completely different variables, pointing to different parts of your computer's memory, but the contents at which they are pointing to are the same.

I think your confusion stems from the equality check that you are doing `x==y`. This checks the **contents** of `x` against the **contents** of `y` and if they are equal, it returns true. However it does not say that they are the same variable. Try this expression `x is y` it will return `False` or `id(x) == id(y)` which will also return `False` as the two variables are pointing to different locations in memory.

That said, of course when you change `x` after copying its contents into `y`, `y` will not be affected.

Comment: My bad. I was on auto-pilot, thinking `==` for reference types checks for reference. Wasn't aware of `is` operator. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @CodeScrat Also, there's no "reference types" (alternatively: all types are reference types).